# Getting error will access the oauth token using spring security and spring boot with oauth2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am implementing Spring security with Spring boot and Oauth2 with Spring boot Release 1.5.12.RELEASE

Getting this error will trying to get the access token

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.email as email2_1_, user0_.mobilenumber as mobilenu3_1_, user0_.password as password4_1_, user0_.role_id as role_id6_1_, user0_.username as username5_1_ from user user0_ where user0_.username=?
```

> 2018-04-25 10:17:39.707  INFO 16592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error:
>   InternalAuthenticationServiceException, null
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter.getOAuth2Authentication(ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter.java:71)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AbstractTokenGranter.getAccessToken(AbstractTokenGranter.java:70)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AbstractTokenGranter.grant(AbstractTokenGranter.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.vp.learning.SpringSecurityDemo.model.CustomUserDetails.(CustomUserDetails.java:21)
>     at
>   com.vp.learning.SpringSecurityDemo.SpringSecurityDemoApplication.lambda$0(SpringSecurityDemoApplication.java:42)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:114)
>     ... 107 more

My Classes looks like this 
**AuthorizationServerConfig**

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Autowired
 AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


@Autowired
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    clients.inMemory().withClient("my-client-id")
    .authorizedGrantTypes("client-credentials","password")
    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT","ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
    .scopes("read","write","trust")
    .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(500)
    .secret("secret");


}
 @Bean
    public WebResponseExceptionTranslator loggingExceptionTranslator() {
        return new DefaultWebResponseExceptionTranslator() {
            @Override
            public ResponseEntity<OAuth2Exception> translate(Exception e) throws Exception {
                // This is the line that prints the stack trace to the log. You can customise this to format the trace etc if you like
                e.printStackTrace();

                // Carry on handling the exception
                ResponseEntity<OAuth2Exception> responseEntity = super.translate(e);
                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.setAll(responseEntity.getHeaders().toSingleValueMap());
                OAuth2Exception excBody = responseEntity.getBody();
                return new ResponseEntity<>(excBody, headers, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
            }
        };
    }
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
   endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager) .exceptionTranslator(loggingExceptionTranslator());

}
```

}

**ResourceServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
```

@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/","/h2_console","/register","/login").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/secure/**").authenticated();

}
```

}

**SpringSecurityDemoApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

public class SpringSecurityDemoApplication {

```
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;    

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringSecurityDemoApplication.class, args);
}

@Autowired
public void authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder, UserRepository repository, UserService service) throws Exception {
    //Setup a default user if db is empty
    if (repository.count()==0)
        service.save(new User("user", "user", new Role("USER")));
    User u =repository.findByUsername("user");
    System.out.println(u);
    builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService(repository)).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}

/**
 * We return an istance of our CustomUserDetails.
 * @param repository
 * @return
 */
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService(final UserRepository repository) {
    return username -> new CustomUserDetails(repository.findByUsername(username));
}
```

}

**CustomUserDetails**

```
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {

/**
 * 
 */
private String username;
private String password;
private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;
public CustomUserDetails(User byUsername) {
    this.username = byUsername.getUsername();
    this.password =byUsername.getPassword();
     this.authorities = translate(byUsername.getRole());
}

  private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> translate(Role roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+roles.getName()));
        return authorities;
    }
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return authorities;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return password;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return username;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}
```

}

Defined other classes as well

This is how i am hitting the rest API

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN1dp.png)